# Resend notification email for add user with askpassword in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerService addUser webservice with askPassword option set to true.How to resend this email .Since we are using different templates for Ask Password and Password reset ,we cannot use sendRecoveryNotification api.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by different templates ? do you modify existing templates ? You can trigger ask password flow by adding user with empty password.
Thanks
Isura

Comment: Yes We modify existing templates for ask password and resetPassword with different links in our application. If i add user again it throws user already exists